# How do I write a "like 'somevalue%' in jOOQ?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I haven't been able to find a way to write this statement in jOOQ:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column like 'hello%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry -- I was having a completely unrelated problem manifesting itself in an error on my jOOQ where clause that I discovered moments after posting the question (of course!)

The answer is simple:

`newCondition = field( columnName ).like( value );`

Move along, nothing to see here.   :)